# JPlayer issues with Firefox 3.6.4

Tags: jplayer

I'm having some issues with the JPlayer widget.

I'm using JPlayer 1.1.1 with Firefox 3.6.4 and I'm testing this locally on my laptop. I'm all setup to use local domains i.e. http://mylocaldomain, etc.

I have JPlayer in a folder under htdocs called myfolder that I access by going to http://myfolder. I have a test script setup just like the playlist demo on the JPlayer Web site (http://www.happyworm.com/jquery/jplayer/latest/demo-02.htm).

When I load my test script in Firefox it plays like half a second of the audio track. However, my script works fine using Safari and Chrome, and plays the tracks in sequence.

Is there a way to not use the .swf as I have been seeing in other posts as it's becoming really annoying trying to debug this for Firefox when it works in other browsers. I've tried various swfPath settings but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I just completed a JPlayer project using Firefox 3.6.10 as the main dev browser, and JPlayer 1.2.0, and I did not see an issue with it cutting off as you describe. You might try upgrading to JPlayer 1.2.

However there is this in the dev guide:
"Firefox 3.6 (Windows, Mac) †
...
    * When using {oggSupport: true}, the browser appears to enable file seeking, which can cause the music to pause briefly when a new play position is selected."

Comment: Thanks. I've upgraded to JPlayer 2.0 but I still have the pause in Firefox. Do you know any way I can eliminate this?

Comment: Try loading my page in Firefox and see if it works for you... oh, let me post a new answer so I can format it... just a minute here...

Answer (score 0):

Again, I don't think I saw the problem you mentioned. However, that means I do have working code. Have you tested on multiple machines, and what OS are you running Firefox on?

Try loading my application in your Firefox ( http://alinesoundscape.org/ )and see if it works. If so, I can post the relevant parts of my source and you can compare with what you have.